# Writing encapsulated dynamic size of data to a text file in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I am making a program which adds dynamic data to a file. The dynamic data is in form of linked list.
For example consider the following data:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  struct abc
  {
    int a;
    struct abc *next;
  };

  int main()
  {
    abc obj1;
    abc obj2;
  }
```

How can I add these objects to file? I can't write the pointer addresses. I have to write values but how can I put delimiter to distinguish between two objects? I can't simply read the objects using `read()` functions.

Please suggest some good ways to do it.

Comment: That doesn't look like [tag:C]

Comment: If it's just a list that holds nothing more than one `int`, only write these `int`s to a file, and rebuild the list when you read them from the file again.

Comment: i want to store multiple lists of int and how can i distinguish between the two lists while reading. i want to store the encapsulate data

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fstream` library to read and write data to files.
You can add a method to your class which can handle writing the data of the object to file or to create another class which will handle reading and writing the list of objects to and from the file.

Comment: as i am not writing the object directly , i am writing each value so ho can i distinguih between th two objects while reading

Comment: @user2992191 since it's a class you are designing, you can decide on your own delimiter.  For example, you can use a comma to separate values of the same objects and a newline char to distinguish between different objects

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide on a protocol to use.

You could do it like this:

```
void write_abc(FILE *f) {
    // count the number of elements in the list. Write the number to the file.

    // write the numbers.
}

struct abc read_abc(FILE *f) {
    // Read a number from the file. This is the number of elements in the list.

    // Read that number of elements and add to a new list.

    // Return the new list
}
```

Comment: In C there is no standard way of doing it. Just decide on a way to format your data. You could also use protocols/formats that are better at handling future changes to the struct layout, like JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that pointers will have addresses that were assigned in runtime. If you read pointer addresses from a file which was created by another executable, or by the same executable during another execution, the addresses will not be the same.

What you'll want to do is to simply store the integer part of each node into the file, in the order they appear in the linked list. Simply keep storing them until you reach the end of the list.

Then when reading, re-build the whole linked list, upon reading the file value by value. Keep reading until you reach the end of the file.